# how to pass regular expression as parameter python

Tags: python, regex, arguments, optparse

I have a linux folder containing multiple files:

```
    $Files_samples  ls 
    Sample_6_5_control1.fastq
    Sample_6_5_control1_fastqc.html
    Sample_6_5_control1_fastqc.zip
```

and i want to pass my python script a regular expression (regex) describing some of them for example

`python Syncit.py -I /Files_samples/Sample*`

my code is:

```
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option('-I','--inputPath', help = 'directory or a file to sync' ,dest='inputPath')
    inputPath=opts.inputPath
    print inputPath
```

my output would be:

```
    Sample_6_5_control1.fastq
```

which is the first file found match to Sample*, what i really want is to pass the `/Files_samples/Sample*` argument as string to be use later with `glob.glob` function.

thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   In this case, you do not describe a problem you are having.

Comment: `/Files_samples/Sample*` you'd need to quote that to prevent the shell from expanding it

Answer (score 0):

I would add another argument, called pattern, like this:

```
parser.add_option('--pattern', dest='pat')
```

And then

```
inputPath = os.path.join(opts.inputPath, opts.pat)
```

You can then call your script like so:

```
python Syncit.py -I /Files_samples --pattern Sample*
```

Comment: i will still have just the first file while i'm looking for all of them. linux interprets Sample* to Sample_6_5_control1.fastq  when i call the script: `python Syncit.py -I /Files_samples --patern Sample*` as the first